# hadoop distcp exception can't rename tmp file

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, distcp

I am trying to move data from one cdh(CDH4.7.1) cluster to another cdh(cdh5.4.1) cluster using distcp command as below :

```
 hadoop  distcp -D mapred.task.timeout=60000000  -update     hdfs://namenodeIp of source(CDH4):8020/user/admin/distcptest1 webhdfs://namenodeIp of target(CDH5):50070/user/admin/testdir
```

With this command directories and subdirectories are copied from source cluster cdh4 to target cluster cdh5 but files from source cluster are not being copied to target cluster failing with the below error:

Fail to rename tmp file (=webhdfs://10.10.200.221:50070/user/admin/testdir/_distcp_tmp_g79i9w/distcptest1/account.xlsx) to destination file (=webhdfs://10.10.200.221:50070/user/admin/testdir/distcptest1/account.xlsx)

The stacktrace found in the logs of that job is as follows:

```
2016-02-19 03:16:57,006 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2016-02-19 03:16:58,686 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2016-02-19 03:16:58,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=MAP, sessionId=
2016-02-19 03:16:59,736 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2016-02-19 03:16:59,752 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@715f1f9c
2016-02-19 03:17:00,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://n1.quadratics.com:8020/user/admin/.stagingdistcp_g79i9w/_distcp_src_files:0+2443
2016-02-19 03:17:00,345 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Counter name MAP_INPUT_BYTES is deprecated. Use FileInputFormatCounters as group name and  BYTES_READ as counter name instead
2016-02-19 03:17:00,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 0
2016-02-19 03:17:01,098 INFO org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp: FAIL distcptest1/account.xlsx : java.io.IOException: Fail to rename tmp file (=webhdfs://10.10.200.221:50070/user/admin/testdir/_distcp_tmp_g79i9w/distcptest1/account.xlsx) to destination file (=webhdfs://10.10.200.221:50070/user/admin/testdir/distcptest1/account.xlsx)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.rename(DistCp.java:494)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.copy(DistCp.java:463)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:549)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:316)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.rename(DistCp.java:490)
... 11 more

2016-02-19 03:17:10,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp: FAIL distcptest1/_distcp_logs_ww86cq/_logs/history/job_201602160057_0105_1455872921915_hdfs_distcp : java.io.IOException: Fail to rename tmp file (=webhdfs://10.10.200.221:50070/user/admin/testdir/_distcp_tmp_g79i9w/distcptest1/_distcp_logs_ww86cq/_logs/history/job_201602160057_0105_1455872921915_hdfs_distcp) to destination file (=webhdfs://10.10.200.221:50070/user/admin/testdir/distcptest1/_distcp_logs_ww86cq/_logs/history/job_201602160057_0105_1455872921915_hdfs_distcp)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.rename(DistCp.java:494)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.copy(DistCp.java:463)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:549)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:316)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.rename(DistCp.java:490)
... 11 more
```

Got the above error even after using this command as well:

```
 hadoop  distcp -D mapred.task.timeout=60000000  -update     webhdfs://namenodeIp of source(CDH4):50070/user/admin/distcptest1 webhdfs://namenodeIp of target(CDH5):50070/user/admin/testdir
```

WebHDFS is enabled in both the clusters.

Regarding execution of the distcp command I did that from my source cluster that is cdh4 with user as 'admin' and its possible as per the cloudera link given below:

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_data_cluster_migrate.html

When I monitored target cluster file from source cluster is not being written to temporary folder created by distcp in target cluster.That's the reason why rename is failing in the target cluster since the target path doesn't contain that file.Can someone tell why file writing is failing ?

I've searched related posts on stackoverflow and tried those solutions  but none of them couldn't fix this problem.Any ideas of fixing this would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is a user that is not able to run yarn jobs, it will most likely be a banned user in your YARN config.

If this is a secure cluster, you need a trust between both kerberos domains aswell.

Comment: Both the clusters are not secured and they both operate on simple authentication.I tried with user as 'admin' as well but still got the same error using the below command: HADOOP_USER_NAME=admin hadoop  distcp -D mapred.task.timeout=60000000 -D mapreduce.job.queue.name=default -update  -skipcrccheck  hdfs://srcNamenodeIp:8020/user/admin/QuadDemo webhdfs://targetNamnodeIp:50070/user/admin/dest

Comment: does this user exist on every datanode as well as hdfs? Does this user have read access on the source and write access on the destination? In case of HA hdfs, is the active namenode the one you use on both sides?

Comment: yes user 'admin' exists in all datanodes and  exists in destination cluster as well and user 'admin' is the owner of those both source and target directories.He has all permissions on both sides.Directories and sub-directories are copied from source to destination cluster.Only problem is with the files that are present in directory.

Comment: Is it because files in the directory has only read and write permissions but no execute permissions for the owner itself?If yes ,how to set execute permissions for those files as when I executed :hadoop fs -chmod  777 /user/admin/QuadDemo/total_tokens_by_hour-20091111.tsv execute permissions are not set to the file

Comment: You should not need to chmod to 777 to achieve this. who owns the destination directory? and if it doesn't exist yet, the one above that ?

Comment: both source and destination directories are owned by same user and the destination directory exists. Sub directories within source directory are getting copied to the destination cluster.Only the files in the directory are not getting copied to the  destination cluster with the above exception.

Comment: Is it because of directory permissions which is read,write,execute for owner;read,execute for group and execute only for others?Can we pass user group information along with permissions in the distcp command inorder to solve this?